# setting up single sign on with django-cas and django-mama-cas

Tags: python, django, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

Im looking into setting up single sign on for a django website. My search brought me to django-mama-cas and django-cas-ng but Im not sure whether I can or should use them separately or together.

The mandatory CAS_SERVER_URL setting for django-cas-ng also confuses me because it gives me the impression that I might need a third party service to get django-cas-ng to work.

https://github.com/jbittel/django-mama-cas, 
https://github.com/mingchen/django-cas-ng

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They work together, but not in the same Django project. On one hand, you have to create a Django project and install [django-mama-cas](https://github.com/jbittel/django-mama-cas). Let's say you already installed it and it lives in **cas-server.example.com**.

On the other hand, if you have another django project living in **foobar.example.com**, then you have to modify that project installing and configuring [django-cas-ng](https://github.com/mingchen/django-cas-ng). Here is where you have to set `CAS_SERVER_URL = "cas-server.example.com"`.

So, **foobar.example.com** is the client, **cas-server.example.com** is the server.

Then, if you have another Django project, let's say **other-project.example.com**, you can also install `django-cas-ng` here two and use the Single Sing On for singing in on both projects.

Comment: Can you provide me any tutorial link if possible. Would be great thanks. Because this is too little information

Comment: @AdilMalik just read the docs for django-mama-cas project: http://django-mama-cas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I successfully setup the SSO with mama-cas using session token. But i don't know how to setup sso with rest framework. Does mama-cas support for it ?

Comment: @matagus did you have ssl certificates problem on localdev? I can't seem to fix mine and it only seems to affect /cas/logout flow ...